# trouble with labeling axis with strings using ggplot (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a college student and we have to create some graphs using Rstudio for an assignment. I've managed to do the core objective for this first task, which is to create a simple bar graph with the provided data; however, I'm having trouble with labeling the axes with the desired text.

Here's the code:

```
library (ggplot2)

Country = as.factor(c("slovakia", "iceland", "lithuania"))
Waste = c(2.0, 3.7, 2.1, 2.3, 1.7, 2.5)
Year = as.factor(c("2004", "2018"))

data = data.frame(Country, Waste, Year)

ggplot(data,                                    
       aes(x = Country,
           y = Waste,
           fill = Year)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge") 
 xlab("Country")
   ylab("Tons of waste per capita")
```

This is the output:
[image]

But I want the axis labels to have this specific text (made with Word):
[image]

Please note that we were specifically asked to use `ggplot`.

Comment: Nice advice from AndrewGB.  Also see the R equisse package: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/esquisse/versions/1.1.0  It is a very nice drag and drop ggplot builder for R.  You can build out an advanced plot and then copy and paste the code that is generated into R studio to fine tune.  There are some tutorial vids on YouTube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ggplot2`, you have to use `+` at the end of your line of code to add additional layers to your plot. If not, then R just reads those lines of code as standalone lines, which will throw an error. So, in your code, the sign is missing at the end of `geom_bar` and `xlab`, which means the x and y label lines are never added to your plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data,                                    
       aes(x = Country,
           y = Waste,
           fill = Year)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge") +
xlab("Country") +
ylab("Tons of waste per capita")
```

**Output**

[image]

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(Country = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), class = "factor", levels = c("iceland", 
"lithuania", "slovakia")), Waste = c(2, 3.7, 2.1, 2.3, 1.7, 2.5
), Year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), class = "factor", levels = c("2004", 
"2018"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```